# MySQL dump restore - how to retain comments

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

So I have that complex MySQL dump as a backup. Unfortunately, that backup is complex and we use evil triggers.

Some of our evil triggers had a comment lines starting with the # character.

When I backup the database, the resulting dump save the # lines. The problem is when I am doing the restore. The line starting with # are replaced by empty lines.

So I am looking for a way to restore the dump WITH the lines starting with the pound.

Comment: Could you provide additional information? What is the version of MySQL Server? What method you use for restoring - is it via mysql command line client, through external program like DBVisualizer, or some other way? And how did you originally crate the triggers with the "#" comment lines, what tool or client was used?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

OMG I know your problem !!!

Here is the problem: The mysql client filters out comments.

```
-c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
                    default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
                    with --comments.
```

Just load the mysqldump file like this:

```
mysql -u... -p... --comments < dumpfile.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: deleting my response; yours seems more legit

Comment: Deleting my answer as well. Looks like `--comments` option is introduced starting from MySQL 5.0.52 and MySQL 5.1.23.

Comment: It is creating comments in dump file, but when restoring DB using mysql source command, comments are getting removed.